# Using the values in the layout page in the child views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have layout page for my mvc webpage where i have done the stuff like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="header">
<div>
   @{
            SessionDetail sess = new SessionDetail();
            ICacheProvider cache = (ICacheProvider)DIConfig.GetInstance("cacheprovider");
            sess = (SessionDetail)cache.Get(Session["usersession"].ToString());
           }      
             <div id="menu" align="right">
            <li class="first" style="list-style-type: none;">Welcome <b>**@sess.DisplayName**</b>! |@Html.ActionLink("Logout","Logout","Account")</li>
            </div>
            <div class="site-title">
                <h2>Dheutto</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div align="right">@Html.ActionLink("Show Devices","Index","Device")</div>
      </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Now from here i have the session details in sess object. Is it possible for me to carry the value in sess object to all the view pages that render under this layout page?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: ya i tried it using in my view page as @sess.displayname but the does not render as it throws error.

Comment: Try to put in the ViewBag: `ViewBag.sess = sess` and us it with `@ViewBag.sess.displayname`

Comment: tried it but view bag returns only empty value  i couldn't get the data. Should i initialize viewbag in layout page?